# mkfs doesn't work -- hangs on "Creating journal"

Tags: linux, command-line, mkfs

I needed to reformat my 14GB stick to ext4. I used `mkfs.ext4`. But this program hung on `Creating journal`

Neither Ctrl c nor `kill -9` could interrupt this. I rebooted and now there is a similar problem again.

Why so and how to fix it?

I am using linux 5.10 [Manjaro](https://manjaro.org) distribution (if it matters at all)

---

[image]

Comment: How long did you wait for it to complete?

Comment: More than hour.

Comment: Run `badblocks` on it. It might be faulty. Also check `dmesg` for errors.

Comment: You won't belive badblock is too not responding

Comment: Check the output of `dmesg`: I guess you'll find I/O errors, indicating that the USB has failed.

Comment: Yes it was I/O error

Answer (score 2):

It was I/O error. To ensure that, use
`sudo dmesg -l crit,err` and look for I/O error

Comment: I had a similar issue but it eventually completed. I was creating an Ext4 FS on LUKS on a **256G USB 3.2 drive**, not sure why it took so long, but eventually it finished.